# Retrieving an overall total of points and a weekly total within the same query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query my reward database to work out how many points members of staff have allocated *in total* and *this week*.

The query that I'm using to work out the *total* points a teacher has allocated is as follows:

```
SELECT  `Giver_ID` , SUM(  `Points` ) AS TotalPoints
FROM  `transactions` 
GROUP BY  `Giver_ID` 
ORDER BY  `Giver_ID` ASC
```

The query that I'm using to work out *weekly* allocations is very similar:

```
SELECT  `Giver_ID` , SUM(  `Points` ) AS WeeklyPoints
FROM  `transactions`
WHERE ( `Datetime` >= '2012-09-24' AND `Datetime` <= '2012-09-30' )
GROUP BY  `Giver_ID` 
ORDER BY  `Giver_ID` ASC
```

My question is this: **is it possible to combine the queries to produce `Giver_ID`, `TotalPoints` and `WeeklyPoints` from a single query?**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use a `View` in the SQl database, or `Transactions` in your code? Or even `Select 'Giver_ID', 'TotalPoints', 'WeeklyPoints' FROM 'Transactions'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible -

```
SELECT
  Giver_ID,
  SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints,
  SUM(IF(Datetime >= '2012-09-24' AND Datetime <= '2012-09-30', Points, NULL)) AS WeeklyPoints
FROM transactions
GROUP BY Giver_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT  a.`Giver_ID` , 
            MAX(b.`TotalPoints`) as `TotalPoints`, 
            MAX(c.`WeeklyPoints`) as `WeeklyPoints`
    FROM  `transactions` as a 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Giver_ID`, SUM(`Points`) AS TotalPoints FROM `transactions` GROUP BY `Giver_ID`) as b ON a.`Giver_ID`=b.`Giver_ID`
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Giver_ID`, SUM(`Points`) AS WeeklyPoints FROM `transactions` WHERE ( `Datetime` >= '2012-09-24 00:00:00' AND `Datetime` <= '2012-09-30' ) GROUP BY `Giver_ID`) as c ON a.`Giver_ID`=c.`Giver_ID`
    GROUP BY  a.`Giver_ID` 
    ORDER BY  a.`Giver_ID` ASC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Your query works correctly but runs 2 seconds slower on my install than @Devart's.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  `Giver_ID` , SUM( `Points`) AS WeeklyPoints,(SELECT SUM(`Points`)
FROM  `transactions` where `Giver_ID`=t.`Giver_ID` GROUP BY  `Giver_ID`)  AS TotalPoints
FROM  `transactions` t
WHERE ( `Datetime` >= '2012-09-24' AND `Datetime` <= '2012-09-30' )
GROUP BY  `Giver_ID` 
ORDER BY  `Giver_ID` ASC
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your query. Unfortunately it doesn't show rows where the user hasn't spent any points this week. I probably should've specified that I needed "NULL" values for that.